# Sending value of rows to webservice in JSON format (Android)

Tags: java, android, json, listview, layout-inflater

[Rating Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyTos.png)

Task: Application is receiving values in JSON format and Student Name and Current rating are populated dynamically in the List View. Now, application need to send rating and comments for individual student in JSON format.
Problem: The values given in Rating and comment can be retrieved in Adapter class(where a single row is populated) but cannot be accessed outside this class. I want to access these values within ListView.onClickListener method.

This is Adapter class:

```
class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Student> studentList;
    ArrayList<Student> studentList1;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public StudentAdapter(ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
        this.studentList = studentList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(RatingActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return studentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowactivity3, parent, false);
        //  TextView id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        final RatingBar rv=(RatingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        final RatingBar rv1=(RatingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        final Button b1=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
        final String[] values = {null,null};
        name.setText(studentList.get(position).getSname());
        rv1.setRating(studentList.get(position).getRate());
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RatingActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Comment here:");

                final EditText input = new EditText(RatingActivity.this);
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                builder.setView(input);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("comment",m_Text);
                        values[0]=m_Text;
                        b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
        return row;
    }
}
```

This is layout of single row:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:text="enter name.."
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="@style/customRatingBar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDialog"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:text="Click"/>
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:stepSize="0.1" />
```

Comment: You can try ListView.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: I have tried that, it's not working when Rating bar and buttons are present in row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create interface

   ```
   public interface AdapterItemClickListener {
      void AdapterItemClicked(int position, Bundle data);
   }
   ```
2. Then add code in your adapter class:

   ```
   class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   ArrayList<Student> studentList;
   ArrayList<Student> studentList1;
   LayoutInflater inflater;
   AdapterItemClickListener adapterItemClickListener;

   public StudentAdapter(ArrayList<Student> studentList) {
   this.studentList = studentList;
   inflater = LayoutInflater.from(RatingActivity.this);
   }

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
   return studentList.size();
   }

   @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
   return studentList.get(position);
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView,     ViewGroup parent)
   {
   final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowactivity3, parent, false);
   //  TextView id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
   TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
   final RatingBar rv=(RatingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
   final RatingBar rv1=(RatingBar)row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
   final Button b1=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btnDialog);
   final String[] values = {null,null};
   name.setText(studentList.get(position).getSname());
   rv1.setRating(studentList.get(position).getRate());
   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RatingActivity.this);
           builder.setTitle("Comment here:");

           final EditText input = new EditText(RatingActivity.this);
           input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
           builder.setView(input);

           builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   m_Text = input.getText().toString();
                   Log.d("comment",m_Text);
                   values[0]=m_Text;
                   b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
            //pass your data in bundle and pass adapter position 
        adapterItemClickListener.AdapterItemClicked(position,bundle); 
        dialog.cancel();  
               }
           });
           builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
           builder.show();
       }
   });
   return row;
   }

   // create adapter item click listener and call from fragment or activity class
   public void setAdapterItemClickListener(AdapterItemClickListener adapterItemClickListener){
       this.adapterItemClickListener=adapterItemClickListener;
    }

   }
   ```
3. Then call studentAdapter.setAdapterItemClickListener(this) from fragment or activity and override  void AdapterItemClicked(int position, Bundle data); . You get data in bundle in this method.

Note: This code not tested. So if you face any problem then debug and check. I hope this will work.

Comment: Please tell how to implement studentAdapter.setAdapterItemClickListener(this) in activity.

Comment: Call `studentAdapter.setAdapterItemClickListener(this)` from activity where you set `StudentAdapter`. Then `studentAdapter.setAdapterItemClickListener(this)` show error for override AdapterItemClicked(int position, Bundle data) method. So you have to override `AdapterItemClicked(int position, Bundle data)` method.

Comment: Done now. Thanks. but another ask is allowed sir?

Comment: Yes. You can ask

Comment: I want that rating bar values(inputted) remain Intact even wen ListView is scrolled(as of now ratings disappear when ListView is scrollled)

Comment: I think its your adapter class issue. Test data set in adapter class.